# Python - sum values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have got pretty simple list:

```
example_list = [
    {'points': 400, 'gold': 2480},
    {'points': 100, 'gold': 610},
    {'points': 100, 'gold': 620},
    {'points': 100, 'gold': 620}
]
```

How can I sum all *gold* values? I'm looking for nice oneliner.

Now I'm using this code (but it's not the best solution):

```
total_gold = 0
for item in example_list:
    total_gold += example_list["gold"]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as the name of a local variable - doing so shadows the built-in `list` type and can cause problems.

Comment: You're right, I'm use this only for this example.

Comment: @sigo -- In this case, a nice one-liner exists, but generally, restricting answers to "nice one-liners" is probably a bad idea (as nicer multi-liners might exist).

Answer (score 226, accepted):

```
sum(item['gold'] for item in myList)
```

Answer (score 31):

If you're memory conscious:

```
sum(item['gold'] for item in example_list)
```

If you're extremely time conscious:

```
sum([item['gold'] for item in example_list])
```

In most cases just use the generator expression, as the performance increase is only noticeable on a very large dataset/very hot code path.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map/1247490#1247490) for an explanation of why you should avoid using map.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889611/one-liner-to-determine-if-dictionary-values-are-all-empty-lists-or-not/5889662#5889662) for some real-world timing comparisons of list comprehension vs generator expressions.

Comment: why does a similar `sum(item.gold for item in example_list)` not work? I get a `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'gold'`

Comment: Because the dict type has no attribute (type member) named 'gold'. You're probably confusing Python for JavaScript. In JS, you can use either dot notation or index notation, as the dict-like object there is generally just a plain old JS object. In Python dicts are dicts, and you must use the index operator, so, long answer long: you want `item['gold']` instead of `item.gold`.

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer `map`, this works too:

```
 import operator
 total_gold = sum(map(operator.itemgetter('gold'),example_list))
```

But I think the generator posted by g.d.d.c is significantly better.  This answer is really just to point out the existence of `operator.itemgetter`.

Comment: `_reduce = lambda fn, ar: fn( ar[0], _reduce(fn, ar[1:])) if len(ar) > 1 else ar[0]`       `total_gold = _reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), (lambda fn, ar: [fn(ar[i]) for i in xrange(len(ar))])( (lambda x: x["gold"]), example_list))`     

I also think g.d.d.c's answer is good. This answer is really just to point out the existence of lambda :P

Comment: thanks -- comment formatting doesn't seem to respect newlines though, so it looks even worse than it should.

Comment: @Filipq -- Really, I posted the same answer as g.d.d.c did ~30 seconds after he did.  I originally deleted it, but ever since I got the stupid moderator tools, I can still see my deleted answer.  It was bugging me, so I thought to myself, there has to be another somewhat clean way to do this that illustrates something useful ... I probably should just delete it though ... I don't know.  (I'm open to suggestions).

Answer (score 5):

```py
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

sum_dict = reduce(add, (map(Counter, example_list)))
# Counter({'points': 700, 'gold': 4330})
total_gold = sum_dict['gold']
```

Comment: nice, this allows for counting arbitrary items in the dict without having to know all keys (e.g. this would support counting all keys in the dict at once without specifying them all).

Answer (score 0):

```
example_list = [
    {'points': 400, 'gold': 2480},
    {'points': 100, 'gold': 610},
    {'points': 100, 'gold': 620},
    {'points': 100, 'gold': 620}
]

result = np.sum([x['gold'] for x in example_list])


print(result)
```

output

```
 4330
```

Comment: Is that different than using the non `np` sum?