# Python: Sum values in a dictionary based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that has `Key:Values.`

The values are integers. I would like to get a sum of the values based on a condition...say all values > 0 (i.e).

I've tried few variations, but nothing seems to work unfortunately.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692613/python-sum-values-in-dictionary

Answer (score 11):

Try using the `values` method on the dictionary (which returns a generator in Python 3.x), iterating through each value and summing if it is greater than 0 (or whatever your condition is):

```
In [1]: d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'twenty': 20, 'negative 4': -4}

In [2]: sum(v for v in d.values() if v > 0)
Out[2]: 23
```

Comment: Wow, that may be the best example I've seen of a concise explanation in English that maps to a generator expression in such an obvious way that you don't even need to say that's what you're doing. Wish I could give more than +1.

Comment: @abarnert Coming from you that is quite a compliment, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = {'a' : 5, 'b': 8}
>>> sum(value for _, value in a.items() if value > 0)
```