# Find the sum of certain values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, integer

Given a dictionary and an `int` value `p`, I want to return the sum of its values where the key is greater than `p`.

For example:

`{5:3,10:5,15:7,20:9}`, when p = 18
the result is 9

`{20:3,40:5,60:7,80:9}`, when p = 25
the result is 5 + 7 + 9 = 21

`{10:1,20:2,30:3,40:4}`, when p = 29
the result is 3 + 4 =7

What should I do to identify the integer key and sum up the value keys and return an answer?

Comment: `print(sum(v for k, v in data.items() if k > p))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - sum values in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692613/python-sum-values-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
>>> d = {5:3,10:5,15:7,20:9}
>>> sum(v for k, v in d.items() if k > 18)
9
>>> d = {20:3,40:5,60:7,80:9}
>>> sum(v for k, v in d.items() if k > 25)
21
>>> d = {10:1,20:2,30:3,40:4}
>>> sum(v for k, v in d.items() if k > 29)
7
```