# How to merge/sum repeated items in a variable?

Tags: python

I have a variable in which **column 1 is a list of fish names** and **column 2 is the number of that species caught**. There are many repeated fish in column 1 and corresponding catch counts in column 2 (from different sampling/catch instances).

I would like to merge together repeated fish names and sum their corresponding catch counts - so that there are no repeats and each fish has a single integer pair equaling the total number caught.

**Variable visualized:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Fish 1 | 10 |
| Fish 2 | 5 |
| Fish 1 | 5 |
| Fish 3 | 1 |
| Fish 1 | 5 |
| Fish 2 | 3 |

**New desired variable visualized:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Fish 1 | 20 |
| Fish 2 | 8 |
| Fish 3 | 1 |

Not sure where to begin, looking for any guidance/help.

Comment: It depends on the end purpose that this will be used for. If there will be a lot of data processing using these then you should look into the pandas library: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/ . Otherwise if they are stored like a dictionary then you can use the groupby function from the itertools library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Variables don't have columns. Do you have a pandas dataframe by any chance? Can you please provide a *code* example of the situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - sum values in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692613/python-sum-values-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

First convert your data to dataframe
Then

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.concat([df1,df2])
df=df.groupby('column1')['column2'].sum()
```