# Sum values in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem in processing lists that I have 2 lists:
`shop1= [{'status':'1','price':;1200'},{'status':'1','price':'13000'}] shop2= [{'status':'2','price':3000'},{'status':'2','price':'4000'}]`

How can I return the sum of all the prices of shop1, shop2, so?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692613/python-sum-values-in-dictionary

Comment: So when price has the value '700.0', how to calculate the sum of the string?

Comment: Convert to numeric first

Answer (score -1):

For calculating dynamic number of shops input you can use `itertools` with `zip_longest` method. Hence you don't need to worry if the items length are not same.

```
import itertools
shop_items = itertools.zip_longest(shop1, shop2)
total = sum([sum(item["price"] for item in items if item)  for items in shop_items])
```